# How to convert Json Validation Message Into string Message in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm trying to implement custom validation in sails.js. I managed to get the error messages but it's in Json format. I'd like to convert it to a

**My model**

```
    module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        username: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        }
    },

    //model validation messages definitions
     validation_messages: { //hand for i18n & l10n

        email: {
            required: 'Email is required',

            unique: 'Email address is already taken'
        },
        username: {
            required: 'Username is required'
        }
    }
};
```

**my controller:**

```
        create:function(req,res){
        console.log('create');
        console.log(req.param('username'));
        console.log(req.param('email'));

        var Username=req.param('username');
        var Email=req.param('email');

        //console.log(Username);
        //console.log(Username);
        var params=req.params.all();
        console.log(params);
         Employee.create(params).exec(function(err,model){
             if(err){
               if (err.ValidationError) {
                  errors = HandleValidation.transformValidation(Employee, err.ValidationError);
                  console.log(errors);
                 res.json({
                      success:false,
                      errors: errors
                  })
              };
             }

            if(model)
            {
                res.json(model);
             }

         });

       }
```

Js:

```
   $("form").submit(function(){
        var username=$('#username').val();
        var email=$('#email').val();
         var id=$(this).attr('rel');

    $.post('/create', {
      username:username,
      email:email
    }).success(function (data) {


       //var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);

       alert(JSON.stringify(data));

    }).fail(function (data) {

      alert((JSON.stringify(data)));
    });


    });
```

ERROR Message showing like this if I submit empty form:

```
            { username: '', email: '' }
            { email: [ { required: 'Email is required' } ],
            username: [ { required: 'Username is required' } ] }
```

I want Output like this:

```
                 Email is required
                 Username is required
```

Please Help. Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: you can parse the object by using `var obj = JSON.parse(obj)` and then later can access the message like `obj.email`.

Comment: I tried your solution JSON.parse Not working...But data is coming as Object as you said. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an object. Iterate through it to get what you want.

Based on what your stringified JSON object looks like:

```
var errors = data.errors
var errorsString = ""
for(var field in errors) {
    if(errors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < errors[field].length; i++) {
            error = errors[field][i]
            for (var errorType in error) {
                errorsString += error[errorType] + "\n"
            }
        }
    }
}
alert(errorsString)
```

Comment: I tried this code This code trace through string but Output comes as single char like : " Please help

Comment: What? What is the output?

Comment: Can you show me the output of `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` in your success callback?

Comment: output of alert(data):[Object Object] ouput of console.log(data): Object:{errors:Object}

Comment: On the first line of my example, try `var errors = data.errors`